# Heroku error when trying to deploy discord.py bot

Tags: heroku, discord.py

So I did the classic process: git add . git commit -am "initial commit" git push heroku master. But when doing push heroku master it gave an error about buildpacks and pre-receive hook declined. So I manually set the buildpack to heroku/python. And it now gives this error. I am using heroku cli to deploy

```
Enumerating objects: 3, done.
Counting objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Delta compression using up to 12 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 2.77 KiB | 2.77 MiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> App not compatible with buildpack: https://buildpack- 
registry.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/python.tgz
remote:        More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to msdosdiscordbot.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/msdosdiscordbot.git
! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/msdosdiscordbot.git'
```

I would be really happy if someone could help.

Comment: Hello I solved this by adding .gitignore, requirements.txt and Procfile

Answer (score 0):

just add .gitignore requirements.txt and procfile.